# ImpersonateLoggedOnUser fails on shared folder on the same machine

Tags: windows, security, winapi

I am using ImpersonateLoggedOnUser to access shared folder from my application.
When shared folder is on a different machine everything works as expected. 
When the computer in *\\MyComputer\myshare* is the same as the one I am running the application on the access fails. 
When the path is given as *d:\myshare* everything works fine so there is no permission issue here. What else can be done?

Comment: Windows does some trickery when you're accessing a share on the same computer, to prevent it from being a trivial way to bypass UAC (User Account Control). You might be bumping into a side-effect.

Comment: I got it. In case of local machine LogonUserEx should use LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE. The only complication was to find out if it is local folder in the first place.